# Doctrine mapping a single entity class to multiple tables without inheritance

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm, mapping, entity

Is it possible somehow to map a single entity class to two different tables without inheritance?

Something like:

```
<entity name="Acme\Entity\Service" table="organization_service">
    ...
    <many-to-one field="target" target-entity="Acme\Entity\Organization" inversed-by="services">
        <join-columns>
            <join-column name="target_id" referenced-column-name="id" />
        </join-columns>
    </many-to-one>
</entity>

<entity name="Acme\Entity\Service" table="person_service">
    ...
    <many-to-one field="target" target-entity="Acme\Entity\Person" inversed-by="services">
        <join-columns>
            <join-column name="target_id" referenced-column-name="id" />
        </join-columns>
    </many-to-one>
</entity>
```

where entity classes could look like:

```
class Service
{
    ...

    /**
     * @var Person|Organization
     */
    private $target;
}

class Person
{
    ...

    /**
     * @var Service[]
     */
    private $services;
}

class Organization
{
    ...

    /**
     * @var Service[]
     */
    private $services;
}
```

A workaround I've found so far is to create two classes PersonService and OrganizationService with the same content and map them to "person_service" and "organization_service" tables accordingly.

Comment: Nope.  Not possible with Doctrine 2.